# Loadrunner replay http response returns different return_uri than when performed manually from the browser

Tags: https, loadrunner

I have started using HP Loadrunner as part of a performance testing project.
We are trying to hit an initial URL which redirects to an identity server and then redirects to the web portal login screen.
For now I am trying in parallel to see the message exchange in both loadrunner log and browser log (just to compare the two request response messages). For some reason even though the initial HTTP GET message seems to be the same as the browser one the response coming back from the web portal is not the same. So at the location property when i get the rediction url the path is missing the port number at the redirect_uri point (...../url:portnumber2/.....). that creates an issue with the second redirection as instead of getting me to the proper redirection url it takes me to the error page redirection.

so the message exchange in browser looks like below:

```
   Request URL:https://urladdress:portnumber1/
   Request Method:GET
   Status Code:302 
   Remote Address:10.33.5.83:4020
   Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
   Response Headers
   content-length:0
   date:Fri, 25 Aug 2017 06:50:47 GMT
   location:/connect/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Furladdress%3Aportnumber%2F....sign........
   server:.......
   set-cookie:.AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect........
   set-cookie:.AspNetCore.........
   status:302
   x-powered-by:ASP.NET
   x-ua-compatible:IE=Edge,chrome=1
   Request Headers
   :authority:urladdress:portnumber1
   :method:GET
   :path:/
   :scheme:https
   accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
   accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
   accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
   upgrade-insecure-requests:1
   user-agent:.......
```

---

second redirection

---

```
    Request URL:https://urladdress:portnumber2/connect/authorize?......
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:302 
    Remote Address:ipaddress:portnumber2
    Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
    Response Headers
    content-length:0
    date:Fri, 25 Aug 2017 06:50:47 GMT
    location:https://urladdress:portnumber2/account/login?.......
    server:......
    status:302
    x-powered-by:ASP.NET
    Request Headers
    :authority:urladdress:portnumber2
    :method:GET
    :path:/connect/authorize?......
    :scheme:https
    accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8
    cookie:.AspNetCore.......
    upgrade-insecure-requests:1
    user-agent:..........
```

and the message exchange in loadrunner looks the same with the only difference of not including the portnumber2 after the end of the return_uri property.
That results in being redirected to an error page instead of the second redirection.
The script we are using is shown below:

```
  web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "TLS1.2");
web_cleanup_cookies();
web_cache_cleanup();
web_add_auto_header("Accept-Encoding","gzip, deflate, br");
web_add_auto_header("Accept-Language","en-US,en;q=0.8");
web_add_auto_header("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8");
web_add_auto_header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests","1");
web_add_auto_header("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36");

web_set_option("MaxRedirectionDepth","0",LAST);
web_set_max_html_param_len("10000000");

web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=url1",
                      "LB=Location: ",
                      "RB=\r\n",
                      LAST);

web_url("urladdress:portnumber1", 
    "URL=https://urladdress:portnumber1", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=text/html", 
    "Referer=", 
    "Mode=HTTP", 
    LAST);

lr_message("redirected address 1 = %s " ,lr_eval_string("{url1}"));

web_reg_save_param_ex("ParamName=url2",
                      "LB=Location: ",
                      "RB=\r\n",
                      LAST);
web_url("connect",
        "URL={url1}",
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=https://urladdress:portnumber1", 
        "Mode=HTTP",
        LAST);

return 0;
```

I need to know why the port number on a url is not fetched by the http response message( perhaps there is a configuration I need to create). 
Any other comments that might help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error response?

Comment: There is no error just that the http process redirects me to the error page. Since the url is not good.

Comment: Managed to pass the error posted here but now I am getting another LR       error -26499:InternalError - Invalid _pt0wningTask/_ptTaskItem(000000/000000) for mnSocketFD-1596inOnSsslFirstSendStart

Comment: No need its ok found the issue and resolved it I created a new solution and forgot to enter the proper SSL/TLS version. 
The issue was resolved and the solution was to change the web server not to require different sockets than the default ones. So for HTTP we had 4020 port when its 80 the default and for SSL we had 4030 when its 443. By just bringing everything back to default it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that having a double redirection, particularly ones which are temporary, are going to extract a large performance hit.  You have two double handshakes in a row.  This is bad magic, independent of the testing tool being used.  It is poor architecture on the part of your designers/developers.  Cite the defect - Go for a max redirect level of one.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The double handshaking is not the best architecture but this is how the system is so there is not much there. The problem as I posted is not the redirection as such but rather the Location: url that is returned back in the response message as the browser and loadrunner differs ( browser also includes port number where the loadrunner doesn't).